# how to install sqlitebrowser on RHEL

Tags: centos, rhel, rhel8, fedora-25, sqlite-browser

Is it possible to install sqlitebrowser on RHEL 8 with normal yum installation without the need of snap installation ?
If yes, please share the steps.

sudo yum install sqlitebrowser and sudo dnf install sqlitebrowser both fails with the below error:

Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:51:27 ago on Mon 04 Dec 2023 10:44:05 AM IST.
No match for argument: sqlitebrowser
Error: Unable to find a match: sqlitebrowser

Comment: Have u see this https://snapcraft.io/install/sqlitebrowser/rhel ??

Comment: Hi we have seen this, but we do not want to install snap. 
We need need to use a regular RPM package but not with AppImage or Snap package

Comment: Try checking the documentation on the website: https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/ .

Comment: We have tried this but no luck. Below are the steps that were followed:

sudo dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
sudo subscription-manager repos --enable "rhel-*-optional-rpms" --enable "rhel-*-extras-rpms"
sudo subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-$(arch)-rpms
sudo yum install sqlitebrowser 

But it failed with above mentioned error.

Comment: rhel 8 ( -> CentOS 8 ) is based on Fedora 28.  The `sqlitebrowser-3.10.1-5.fc28.x86_64` works perfect  https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/s/sqlitebrowser-3.10.1-5.fc28.x86_64.rpm ..... **Depends** `qscintilla-qt5-2.10.2-3.fc28.x86_64, qhexedit2-qt5-libs-0.8.3-5.fc28.x86_64, qcustomplot-qt5-2.0.0-1.fc28.x86_64` https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/q/